# Most efficient way to add additional rows up to a certain level that are NaN in value for Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series as follows:

[image]

This could vary up to any length. I would like to add additional rows up until a certain index level (240 in this case) that are filled in with NaN.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and extend the index range of `range(1, 236)` to `range(1, 241)` as follows:

```
rr = rr.reindex(range(1, 241))
```

Result:

```
rr.tail(5)


236   NaN
237   NaN
238   NaN
239   NaN
240   NaN
dtype: float64
```